# looping not selecting the last item in the array

Tags: jquery, arrays, algorithm, for-loop

SCRIPT

Calling function from for loop :

```
colorMe(globalStore.data[i].morning,globalStore.data[i].afternoon,globalStore.data[i].evening, globalStore.data[i].UUID);
```

The function

```
var k = 0;
var userarray = [];
var dayarray  = [];
var dayarray2 = [];
var dayarray3 = [];
var data = 0;
function colorMe(param,param_af,param_eve, param2)
{
    /*console.log("DAY "+param);
    console.log("user "+param2);*/
    //console.log("k= "+k);
    console.log("data= "+data);

    userarray.push(param2);
    //console.log("mY "+userarray[k]);
    dayarray.push(param);
    dayarray2.push(param_af);
    //console.log("afternoon "+dayarray2[k]);
    dayarray3.push(param_eve);
    //console.log("evening "+dayarray3[k]);
    //console.log("Day "+dayarray[k]);
    var len = userarray.length;
    console.log("K= "+k);
    for(;data < k;data++)
    {
        //console.log("data="+ data);
    var arr = dayarray[data];
    var arr2 = dayarray2[data];
    var arr3 = dayarray3[data];
    $("div.morning_"+userarray[data]+" span").each(function() {
                if(arr.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {

                  $(this).css("color","#26F525");

                }
            });

            $("div.afternoon_"+userarray[data]+" span").each(function() {
                if(arr2.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {

                  $(this).css("color","#26F525");

                }
            });
            $("div.evening_"+userarray[data]+" span").each(function() {
                if(arr3.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {

                  $(this).css("color","#26F525");

                }
            });

    }
    k++;

}

console.log("data= "+data);  
console.log("k= "+k);
```

Logs for the counters `k` and `data`

I noted  `data= 0` is logged twice and that's why the last item in the array not applying the effects of this function.Its because the `data`only loops until the 6th item while `k` loops until 7th item. So how do I make the `data` also loop until 7th item and prevent it from looping twice in the beginning `(data= 0)`?

Logs

```
 data= 0 //once  
 K= 0  
 data= 0//twice  
 K= 1  
 data= 1  
 K= 2  
 data= 2  
 K= 3  
 data= 3  
 K= 4   
 data= 4  
 K= 5  
 data= 5  
 K= 6  
 data= 6  
 K= 7
```

I tried:

```
for(;data < k;data++)
```

1) replacing the `k` with finite numbers like 7 but it the function
    wouldn't work.
 2) Used `<=` instead of `<` in the for loop still
    cannot.
 3) Defined `var data=1 / var k =1`

Comment: Are you using k and i interchangeably? Because your for loop has k, but when you call `colorMe` you're indexing all the data you pass in with i. Or is that just a typo?

Comment: @MrMadsen, yes I'm using k and data interchangeably but I didn't use i? Where did you notice it?

Comment: The very first code you have posted, in the parameters you're passing to the functions: `colorMe(globalStore.data[i].morning,globalStore.data[i].afternoon,globalStore.data[i].evening, globalStore.data[i].UUID)`

Comment: @MrMadsen, oh yes that from another for loop. The colorMe function is called from another for loop indexed by i. And the i value is equal to k.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Another question: from the code you posted it looks like the `console.log` `K=` and `data=` are happening outside of the `colorMe` function. Is this a typo? If not then what is causing those to run multiple times?

Comment: @MrMadsen, no they are running inside the function..the one above in the post is typo.  When a call made to the function k which defined k=0 is increased to 1 but data still 0. when next call made to function then only it turns out to be 1

Comment: I would suggest use [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 0):

`for(;data < k;data++)`//here since condition is `data < k` so `0<0` will fail which make `k++` but `data` is still `0`.and it will never print `data=7` because of your condition `data < k`.

```
<script>
    var k = 0;
    var data = 0;
    function colorMe()
    {

        console.log("K= "+k);
        console.log("data= "+data);  
        for(;data < k;data++)//here since condition is data < k so 0<0 will fail which make `k++` but `data` is still 0
        {

        }
        k++;

    }


    for(var i=0;i<7;i++){
        colorMe();
    }
    console.log("data= "+data);  
    console.log("k= "+k); 
    </script>
```

Comment: @Vani the easiest will be to identify the last call for `colorMe()` and use `data+1`. or change the condition to `<=` if it does not hurt.

Comment: thats right, but I failed to identify the last call ...I tried it before :(

Comment: @Vani will `<=` work for you since you know the data better.

Comment: no that doesn't work..I can't even use finite number like < 7/ <=7

Comment: what about k++ before  if condition.or give a sample data.

Comment: @Vani you are using i with some condition can't you identify the last value for i.

Comment: Here , the value of i is 3 because you see 3 records are found..The call made to the function 3 times, so k's value also 3 but data's value will be 2 due to the issue we saw just now

Comment: @Vani change your function to this:function `colorMe(param,param_af,param_eve, param2,index)` pass i as index.check `if(index == globalStore.data-1)` in the last of `colorMe`,if true  then print the last index data also.

Comment: @Vani or try what rajesh has suggested.

Comment: @Vani remember that indexing always starts from `0` so id data array length is `7` the last index will be `6`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I am seeing:
The first time you reach this loop `for(;data < k;data++)` both `k` and `data` are equal to zero. Because of this the condition `data < k` is false and therefore `data` never gets incremented, but `k` does because it is incremented outside the loop.
One way to solve this would be to increment `k` **before** the loop instead of after:

```
k++;
for(;data < k;data++) {
...
}
```

#### EDIT

Another solution is to change the loop to `for(;data <= k;data++)`. Here is a working fiddle demonstrating it: https://jsfiddle.net/eumepcvd/1/
I would try that again, if it doesn't work then your bug might be in code you haven't posted.

#### EDIT 2

Here is another working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qm5mxe7q/1/ 
That one is forked from the fiddle you linked to in your comment.
**Also please note that the 7th item in the array is item 6 because it is zero indexed.** If you want to reach index 7 then there needs to be 8 items in the array.

Comment: nor k++ or data++ before the for loop help the case..They have to be placed after

Comment: no that doesn't work tried already..Could you check this fiddle see if you get idea on this, http://jsfiddle.net/72L8Lnnm/